# Perform operations on an array and store results in a list of lists

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I want to perform an operation on a list multiple times so that my output is a list of lists containing the possible combinations of outputs. In this case I want to substract a value from the list once, but repeat it for each element. So in this example I want to subtract one from one element in the list, store that, then repeat for the next element:

```
input1 = [1, 2, 3, 0, 4]
output1 = [[0, 2, 3, 0, 4], [1, 1, 3, 0, 4], [1, 2, 2, 0, 4], [1, 2, 3, 0, 3]]
```

These values will always be ints and if a value is less than 1, then the function will not subtract from it.

Right now I have a while loop that populates a list with the list input1 for every time a value in input1 is >=1. I made a second while loop to try to accomplish the subtraction, but it just subtracts 1 from any number>= 1.

```
i = 0
input1 = [1, 2, 3, 0, 4]
output1 = []
while i < int(len(input1)):
    if input1[i] >= 1:
        print('i: ' + str(i))
        print(input1[i])
        output1.append(input1)
    i += 1
print(output1)
j = 0
k = 0
while j < int(len(output1)) or k < int(len(input1)):
    print('j: ' + str(j) + ', k: ' + str(k))
    if output1[j][k] < 1:
        print(output1[j][k])
        k += 1
    elif output1[j][k] >= 1:
        output1[j][k] = output1[j][k] - 1
        print(output1[j][k])
        k += 1
        j += 1
print(output1)
```

With this code, on the final line output1 prints:

```
[[0, 1, 2, 0, 3], [0, 1, 2, 0, 3], [0, 1, 2, 0, 3], [0, 1, 2, 0, 3]]
```

What is going wrong here? And is there a more effective way to do this, perhaps using itertools?

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Comment: @MooingRawr. While you are at it: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/256331/2988730, https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/98026/346663

Comment: While I agree that the question doesn't show significant effort from OP, I don't think it's unclear what they are asking.

Comment: The edit seems to show enough effort from the OP now, and I agree that the question itself is clear.

Comment: The power of leaving comments with a responsive OP \o/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is some code that uses the `enumerate` generator to give code that is more Pythonic than it would be otherwise. `enumerate` returns a pair of numbers: the first is the index of the item in the list and the second is the item itself.

```
input1 = [1, 2, 3, 0, 4]
output1 = []
for ndx, item in enumerate(input1):
    if item >= 1:
        tempoutput = input1[:]  # a copy of the list
        tempoutput[ndx] -= 1
        output1.append(tempoutput)
```

The variable `output1` now has the value as desired,

```
[[0, 2, 3, 0, 4], [1, 1, 3, 0, 4], [1, 2, 2, 0, 4], [1, 2, 3, 0, 3]]
```

---

Your original code does not work because you made a common mistake. You build up `output1` in your first section with

```
output1.append(input1)
```

but that just adds another *reference* to the input list to `output1` rather than adding a *copy* of the input list. When you change any one of those sub-lists of `output1` they all are modified simultaneously, because they are all actually the same list. You instead should add a copy of the input list with

```
output1.append(input1[:])
```

(Note that I do the same trick in my code to get a copy of the list.) When that change is made to your code, it then gives the correct answer.

Comment: Thanks for the information, this will probably work. Out of curiosity and ignorance, I put up my original method which used a while loop. Why exactly does this while loop not work? I've never been good with them.

Comment: @fletcht91: See the addition to my answer for an explanation of your mistake and how to correct it. The problem is not in the loop but how you added the input list to your output list.

Answer (score 3):

If you are happy to use a 3rd party library, `numpy` is convenient:

```
import numpy as np

input1 = np.array([1, 2, 3, 0, 4])

n = len(input1)
arr = np.tile(input1, (n, 1))
res = (arr - np.eye(n))[np.where(input1 >= 1)]
```

**Result**

```
array([[ 0.,  2.,  3.,  0.,  4.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  3.,  0.,  4.],
       [ 1.,  2.,  2.,  0.,  4.],
       [ 1.,  2.,  3.,  0.,  3.]])
```

**Explanation**

- Use `numpy.tile` to create an array of shape `(n, n)`.
- Subtract the identity `numpy.eye` to subtract 1 from the diagonal.
- Use `numpy.where` to filter for positive inputs.

**Why use numpy?**

- Performance: Python loops are slower than vectorised `numpy` computations.
- Memory: `numpy` holds numeric data more efficiently than Python lists.
- Syntax: focus on numeric logic rather than multiple `for` & `if` statements.

Comment: Thanks fro the help. I'm already using numpy for dealing with vector operations (specifically numpy.power), so I may use this. Would numpy also be of use if I want to  repeat the subtraction of 1 iteratively so I have every combination of values below and up to the input?

e.g.
    input = [1, 2, 0]
    output = [[1, 2, 0], [0, 2, 0], [1, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0]]

I realize this question is very generic, I'm just looking for general advice on iterations.

Comment: Yep, if you can vectorise it, you can almost certainly do it in `numpy`.. I haven't worked out exactly how to do it in your question, but feel free to post a separate question if you want to go down the `numpy` route.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a basic version that does what you described, improving it is left as an exercise to the reader:

```
input = [1, 2, 3, 0, 4]
output = []

for i, item in enumerate(input):
    current = input[:]
    current[i] = item - 1 if item > 0 else item
    output.append(current)
```

Edit: If the whole operation should be skipped if the current element is less than 1 as implied by the comments, the solution would become:

```
input = [1, 2, 3, 0, 4]
output = []

for i, item in enumerate(input):
    if item > 0:
        current = input[:]
        current[i] -= 1
        output.append(current)
```

Comment: This code appends the input list unchanged if the item is less that one, but the OP wants to leave out the input list in that case. I.e. your result is a list of 5 items but the OP wants 4 items. See the OPs desired output.

Comment: Good point, I was going by "These values will always be ints and if a value is less than 1, then the function will not subtract from it.", which to me does not make it clear that the whole list should be skipped. The first version had 4 inputs and 4 outputs and a bit of a messy edit history so I wasn't quite sure if 4 output elements was intended or an oversight. Only @fletcht91 knows for sure.

Comment: Sorry for the scrappy posting and edits, and thanks for the contribution. I may still find use in this method, it may be convenient to have the original in the list with the -1's.